# Excluir um Limite de Registros Hibernate (Limit)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, select, hql

Estou migrando minha aplicação WEB para o framework `Hibernate`, porém tenho várias requisições `SQL` com parâmetros bem específicos.

Em uma dessas requisições, preciso sempre que incluir um novo registro no banco de dados, excluir os 20 primeiros registros do banco.

Para isto, utilizo o sequinte SQL:

```
DELETE FROM USUARIO WHERE idemp = ? AND codrep = ? AND idcuf NOT IN (SELECT idcuf FROM (SELECT idcuf FROM USUARIO WHERE idemp = ? AND codrep = ? ORDER BY idcuf DESC LIMIT 20) t )
```

Em meu código Hibernate, implementei o seguinte método:

```
public void excluirRegistrosAntigos(UsuariosFVConexao usuario) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;

        String hql = "FROM "
                + "UsuariosFVConexao "
                + "WHERE "
                + "idemp = :idemp AND "
                + "codrep = :codrep AND "
                + "idcuf NOT IN "
                + "(SELECT idcuf "
                + "FROM "
                + "(SELECT idcuf "
                + "FROM "
                + "UsuariosFVConexao "
                + "WHERE "
                + "idemp = :idemp AND "
                + "codrep = :codrep "
                + "ORDER BY idcuf DESC LIMIT 20) t )";

        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            query.setParameter("idemp", usuario.getIdemp());
            query.setParameter("codrep", usuario.getCodrep());
            query.executeUpdate();
            transaction.commit();

        } catch (RuntimeException erro) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            throw erro;
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

O nome da Classe foi mudada neste caso.

Enfim, em meus testes, este método `Hibernate` está me retornando o seguinte erro:

```
ERROR: line 1:265: unexpected token: t
line 1:265: unexpected token: t
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:764)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1796)
    at br.com.portalserver.dao.UsuariosFVConexaoDAO.excluirRegistrosAntigos(UsuariosFVConexaoDAO.java:86)
    at br.com.portalserver.dao.UsuariosFVConexaoDAOTeste.excluir(UsuariosFVConexaoDAOTeste.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter.run(JUnit4TestAdapter.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:535)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:1182)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:1033)
```

Não entendo muito ainda este framework e então não consigo encontrar o erro.
Agradeço desde já.

Muito obrigado

Comment: Você já tentou remover o "t" da query para ver o que acontece?

Comment: Olá Marquezani.  Sim, removi e ele me retorna o seguinte erro:  `ERROR: line 1:255: unexpected token: LIMIT`

Answer (score 0):

O erro ocorre porque o JPQL/HQL **não suporta** `SELECT` logo após a cláusula `FROM`. Segue trecho com o problema:

```
+ "(SELECT idcuf "
+ "FROM "
+ "(SELECT idcuf "
```

Para resolver, você precisa mudar a consulta para não depender deste `SELECT` após o `FROM` ou quebrar a consulta em duas.